# Mount my mtp in my android phone on a directory?

Tags: linux, mount, mtp

I have installed mtp-tools on my debian7.8.
mtp-files can list all my files on android phone.
How can I mount all my files on android phone on the directory  `/tmp/myphone`?

root@debian:/home/debian# jmtpfs  -l
Device 0 (VID=0b05 and PID=0c02) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
Available devices (busLocation, devNum, productId, vendorId, product, vendor):
1, 8, 0x0c02, 0x0b05, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN
root@debian:/home/debian# jmtpfs  /tmp/myphone
Device 0 (VID=0b05 and PID=0c02) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
ignoring usb_claim_interface = -6ignoring usb_claim_interface = -5PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
fuse: bad mount point `/tmp/myphone': Input/output error

The jmptfs can't mount my phone.

```
chmod 777  /tmp/myphone 

After chmod.
```

root@debian:/home/debian# jmtpfs /tmp/myphone
Device 0 (VID=0b05 and PID=0c02) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
root@debian:/home/debian# jmtpfs -l
Device 0 (VID=0b05 and PID=0c02) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
Available devices (busLocation, devNum, productId, vendorId, product, vendor):
1, 5, 0x0c02, 0x0b05, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN

Comment: `fuse: bad mount point '/tmp/myphone': Input/output error `
I think that's the issue here. Is the directory created and writable? Can you try mounting it as a regular user instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install jmtpfs (`aptitude install jmtpfs`) which allows to mount MTP devices.

Create the directory if it doesn't exist already (`mkdir /tmp/myphone`). Then, the following will mount your phone:

```
jmtpfs /tmp/myphone
```

jmtpfs will use the first available device. If you've got more than one connected at a time, you can do `jmtpfs -l` to find out which one is your phone, and use the `-device` flag to specify it.

As an alternative, you can try `go-mtpfs` instead.

Comment: More details on jmtpfs at https://github.com/JasonFerrara/jmtpfs

Comment: Note that `jmtpfs .` (mount into the current directory) does _not_ work, but `jmtpfs $(mktemp -dt phone.XXXXXX)` (mount into a new temporary directory) does.

Comment: Still working in Ubuntu 22.04, this allows to transparently use commands such as `rsync`.

Comment: This didn't work with my MTP device. I get this error `libusb_claim_interface() reports device is busy, likely in use by GVFS or KDE MTP device handling alreadyLIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MtpErrorCantOpenDevice'
  what():  Can't open device
[1]    121957 IOT instruction (core dumped)  jmtpfs /tmp/myphone` I'm on Ubuntu 22.